# onActivityResult() Does not get called?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an `MainActivity` which has two `TextView`. User has an option to start another activity and choose data from `ListView` to fill those `TextView`. My main activity has an `OnClickListener` which starts an `Activty` from which user can select data and come back to main activity.My `OnClickListener` code looks likes this:

```
private static final int PICK_START = 0;
private static final int PICK_END = 1;
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(MainActivity, "view clicked");
        int id = v.getId();

        if (id == R.id.searchR) {
                        //do nothing
        } else if (id == R.id.startSearch) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, SList.class);
            startActivityForResult(startIntent, PICK_START);

        } else if (id == R.id.endSearch) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, SList.class);
            startActivityForResult(startIntent, PICK_END);
        }

    }
```

When the above onClick method gets called and after that its starts another activity **SList.class**.In that I have a listview from which user can select the value and upon selecting value the result will be set and activity will finish itself.Code for this is:

```
sListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Station selectedS = sArray.get(position);
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("_id", selectedS.getId());
                returnIntent.putExtra("name", selectedS.getName());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

In above code activity sets the result and finishes itself.Till here everything is working accordingly.But after that when the previous activity is started, the `onActivityResult()` method nevers gets called.The code for `onActivityResult()` is :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(MainActivity, "" + requestCode);

        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Check which request we're responding to
            if (requestCode == PICK_START) {
                //data.getStringExtra("_id");
                Log.i(MainActivity, data.getStringExtra("name"));

            } else if (requestCode == PICK_END) {
                Log.i(MainActivity, data.getStringExtra("name"));
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont know why onActivityResult is never triggered .Someone even
 wrote on his blog that There is bug in android API. In
 `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);` This function does work
 as long as `requestCode = 0`. However, if you change the request code to
 anything other than zero, the ApiDemos will fail (and onActivityResult()
 won't be called).

Comment: I have 3 different **requestCodes** in my Activity - 0, 10, 11. They all work fine, on API 10 - 17. That shouldn't be a Problem. Can you please provide the link to that blog??

Comment: is the `onItemClick()` called ?? display a Log in that method to verify if it is called or not. And about the requestCode , i've already tried it with requestCode = 1000, , 1001 ...etc it works

Comment: @Houcine yes it gets called and activity finishes itself and the previous activity becomes visible

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Sorry the Link is not available now as it was a google group link and due to lots of spams google has take it down

Comment: @Archie.bpgc It could only be 0 or 1.You can see my above code.

Comment: Oops sry didn't see. Also, found this **check your manifest and make sure you are NOT using single instance:

android:launchMode="singleInstance"**

Comment: @Archie.bpgc I have taken care of this already.Its not in my manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.I just needed to restart my eclipse and my code started working.

Comment: funny solution :) funny Eclipse